# Basic combinatory verification/clarification

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

What is the number of non-descending series of length $k$ ($a_1 \le ... \le a_k$) that are a combination of the numbers $1,...,n$ ($\forall_{1\le i \le k}\ a_i \in\{1,...,n\}$)?

We were taught to solve these questions by answering two questions:

1. Is repetition allowed? (In this case, I know it is. We are asked for non-descending, not ascending)
2. Is the order of sampling of any importance? (I'm not sure about this one. I think we can sample any $k$ items, and we then rearrange them to meet the "non-descending" restriction)
   $$\text{Therefore: } \binom{n+k-1}{k}$$

The reasoning behind the 2nd question seems somewhat lacking to me, because it feels like manipulating our samples (even though it also seems like the right answer to me).

Please help me clarify the matter.

Comment: Can you specify the problem. What do you mean by _non-descending_? So, $a_i>a_{i+1}$ or $a_i\geq a_{i+1}$, and for all $i$ or just for one? And does a combination of numbers allow repetition?

Comment: @Tomas hope it's clearer now.

Comment: According to this definition, I get $210$ such combinations for $k=4,n=7$ - not $1337$.

Comment: Bad wording by me then.
"1337" is an example of a combination which is possible under these restrictions. I'll just remove it. I think that after adding the additional information (thanks to your first reply), it's clear which combinations are possible.

Comment: Haha, sorry, my bad. Now we are clear. Your reasoning in 2) is absolutely fine. Note, that rearranging the chain to meet the condition is possible in _exactly one_ way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer verified. Posting this so I'll be able to mark it as answered.